# “No Application is associated with specified file for this operation”

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, browser

I am opening a website (lets say www.google.com) from my window application (.net 3.5 framework, C#) using Process. Start method. It is working fine on all machines but on a single machine its showing the error “No Application is associated with specified file for this operation”.

Comment: What happens on that single machine? Website not showing up? Or is the hole application not working? Check if the standard browser is set on that machine.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("https://www.google.lk", string.Empty);
process.StartInfo.Verb = string.Empty;

process.Start();
```

The above code full-fill your requirement.

Comment: Not a line of comment to explain what this does?